# Unity C#, override variable type in child class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'll try to do my best to explain myself, but English is not my first language.

**In summary:** I want to override a variable type in a child class or something similar so, my child classes have always the "latest" version of each class.

Right now, I have 2 classes > `Animal` and `AnimalAnimator` and both classes has their child class `Dog` and `DogAnimator`.

`Animal` class looks like this:

```cs
public class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimalAnimator Animator { get; private set; }

    private virtual void Awake()
    {
        Animator = GetComponent<AnimalAnimator>();
        [code...]
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this with Dog:

```cs
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public new DogAnimator Animator { get; private set; }

    private override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();

        Animator = GetComponent<AnimalAnimator>();
    }
}
```

I want `Dog` to extend `Animal`, and override the `AnimalAnimator` component with `DogAnimator` (that extend `DogAnimator`. But Unity is giving me this error:

```
The same field name is serialized multiple times in the class or its parent class. This is not supported: Base(Dog) <Animator>k__BackingField
```

Is this possible in C#? How can I proceed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If `DogAnimator` derives from `AnimalAnimator`, you can assign a `DogAnimator` to `AnimalAnimator Animator { get; private set; }` without changing its type.

Comment: You can make Animal generic and constrain the genetic type parameter to be AnimalAnimator. You can then declare the property to be that type. When Dog inherits Animal, it sets that generic type parameter to be DogAnimator.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have tried that, but by doing that I cannot access DogAnimator "exclusive" Methods.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you give a hint about Generic's approach?

Comment: No what you would do is have an AnimalAnimator which has all the basics, then you can make DogAnimator as a descendant or CatAnimator as a descendant which Dog uses and you can cast then (DogAnimator)Animator....

Comment: I put a sample code for the generics option which I guess @jmcilhinney had in mind.

Comment: @HadiFooladiTalari, your answer is just what I meant but I was on a phone so writing the code myself was not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics like the code sample below.

```cs
class Animal<TAnimator> : MonoBehaviour where TAnimator : AnimalAnimator
{
    public TAnimator Animator { get; private set; }

    public void Awake()
    {
        Animator = GetComponent<TAnimator>();
    }
}

class Dog : Animal<DogAnimator>
{
    public void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always mark the Unity MonoBehavior message methods as `virtual` for those .. otherwise it will be very error prone ;) And then there would be no need to explicitly re-implement `Awake` if it does nothing else but call the base